# Can't get Json Data after an HttpPost Request :

Tags: android, json, rest, http-post

I'm trying to make an `HttpPost` request to a `REST` server, that is supposed to return some `JSON` back, but it returns nothing, and my `HttpResponse` object's `statusLine` is `HTTP/1.1 400`.

This is my **code** :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
 //some code
String login = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Login)).getText().toString();
String password = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Password)).getText().toString();
List<NameValuePair> paramsList=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rquest", "login"));
paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&login", login));
paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&pwd", password));
rq.login2(paramsList);
}

void login2(List<NameValuePair> paramsList)
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://darate.free.fr/rest/api.php");

    try 
    {
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramsList));    
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();  
    String result = null;
    try 
    {  
      HttpResponse sult = httpclient.execute(request);
      Log.i("Hossam: ",sult.toString());
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  
}
}
```

On the server side this is the function that needs to be executed after my request:

**Server Side login function** :

```
private function login(){
        // Cross validation if the request method is POST else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
        if($this->get_request_method() != "POST"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }

        $login = $this->_request['login'];      
        $password = $this->_request['pwd'];

        // Input validations
        if(!empty($email) and !empty($password)){
            if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE login = '$login' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1", $this->db);
                if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_ASSOC);

                    // If success everythig is good send header as "OK" and user details
                    $this->response($this->json($result), 200);
                }
                $this->response('', 204);   // If no records "No Content" status
            }
        }

        // If invalid inputs "Bad Request" status message and reason
        $error = array('status' => "Failed", "msg" => "Invalid Email address or Password");
        $this->response($this->json($error), 400);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your TextViews contains the right login and password?

Comment: I've just checked, the values are correct, I'm suspecting that the problem is in inserting to parameters to the request.

Comment: It might be a Header problem. Check my edited answer...

Comment: Do you have a test username / password we can use?  I used the Chrome extension "Postman" to send some posts using the information you provided.  Of course I used an incorrect username and password, but I got a status response of 200 and a body of "023".  It would be nice to test separately to see if it is truly your Android code or your server side code.

Comment: Yeah i see because i have been modifying my `api.php` on the server, i allowed Httpget as well, it's working fine but no HTTP post so far it must be caused by Android code.

This get request works fine
`http://darate.free.fr/rest/api.php?rquest=login&login=Hossam90&pwd=bismilah`
i want that with post :/

Comment: I used "Postman" to send a post using the information you provided.  I got a response of { "status":"failed","msg":"no entries" }.  Is this correct?  Can you please update all your code (Android and PHP) so we get a fresh idea of where you stand?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also used Json for the request:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "utf-8");
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

In that case you need to correctly construct the **json** parameter.

Example:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("pass", "123");
```

**EDIT:**
 Don't forget this:

```
httppost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset= utf-8");
httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: You need to debug your server and see the incoming request from the server side.

Comment: I haven't done that before, I'm not sure how to do this, on my server side this is how i get params from the Url `_request['login']` if i change that to `urldecode($_POST['name']);` is that going to solve my problem?